# Return single string from database

Tags: android

I have this query in my database helper requesting a `Google map` `URL`string,

```
public String getBeachMap(String id) {
    String[] args = {id};
    String strMap = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT _id, BeachMap FROM Beach WHERE _id=?", args).toString();
    return(strMap);
}
```

And this in my activity,

```
theUrl = dbBeachHelper.getBeachMap(passedVar);      
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), theUrl, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

The passedVar is being sent through and I have no problem returning a cursor, but I just want a string, I think! `theUrl` has some random value in it! Am I close to receiving a string?

Cheers,

Mike.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think

```
String strMap = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT _id, BeachMap FROM Beach WHERE _id=?", args).toString();
```

returns human-readable description of this object

Have you tried this?

```
Cursor c = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT _id, BeachMap FROM Beach WHERE _id=?", args);
    if(c.moveToNext()){
        return(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("BeachMap")));
    }
    c.close();
```

Comment: You think!!! give yourself some credit! That’s exactly the random value I was getting! Your code works perfectly and is just what I needed. Thank you very much and cheers, still learning Mike.